# How to disable Google Chrome text area size adjustment

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, resize, textarea

Is there a way you can think of that yo can avoid Google chrome built in text are adjustment.

See how ugly it looks:

[image]
:)

I know why it's there and I find it a very useful feature but in some design-oriented pages,  you might want to remove it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's in Safari too.

You can disable it [with CSS](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/):

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: damn that was lazy of me. a RTFM question. Thank you littlegreen!

Comment: Well not lazy enough to insert a screenshot. By the way who's lazy, I'm the one only answering RTFM questions :)

Answer (score 8):

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Source: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5f9cd62207e2c7a8&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

We can using mix-width, max-width save value, apply for height value. It's still have rezie cursor at right,bottom.